# Can't connect to network machine by the name specified in the DNS

Tags: networking, domain-name-system, windows-server-2008-r2, hyper-v

I have a virtual machine in Hyper-V using an external network switch. In the network there is a Windows 2008 R2 server which is DC, AD and DNS. In the vm IPV4 settings for the NIC I'm specifying the servers IP as DNS. But when I try to ping the server by name it fails, only the IP works pinging. The DNS does not seem to be able to answer. What could be the possible reason for this?

Host machine runs Windows 8 Pro, and guest machine Windows Server 2008 R2.

Comment: Q: What could be the possible reason for this? A: The VM not having a DNS suffix that matches the DNS zone, so it's sending an unqualified (single label name) DNS query to the server, which the server can't answer.

Comment: Is the VM joined to the AD domain? If not, what @joeqwerty said.

Comment: The VM has its own domain. On saturday I'll try to take some screenshots on the configurations and update the question so it may clear out some questions about the setup. Thanks for all your help so far!